# Bluetooth vanishing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

Hy guys

I have a recurring problem in my Windows 10.

From time to time the bluetooth service is unavailable. Just that. I start my notebook and the service is not there.

But if I enter the running services section it is listed as "running", however, the icon does not appear in the system tray for me to connect. Likewise, if I go in the machine settings it says that the bluetooth is turned off (the option to turn on also is not displayed).

How to make sure this does not happen from time to time?

I know the best answer would be to reinstall the driver, but I do it EVERY TIME = (

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, run the troubleshooter for Bluetooth, see the diagnose report.

Next, Uninstall everything that is Bluetooth-related that is listed in Programs & Features.

Uninstall all Bluetooth-related drivers listed in the Device Manager.

Restart the computer. Bluetooth will be reinstalled.